# Aframe Android Chrome Camera looks always backward

Tags: android, google-chrome, camera, aframe, gyroscope

Hidiho Community,

I have this issue that when I open an aframe-webpage with my Android phone that the camera (or the scene) turns 180 degrees. I use the normal Aframe example https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/helloworld/ but it still happens some ideas how to fix that? I already tried setting the camera rotation to 0 0 0 at the start with javascript but it doesn't work. My Phone is a xiaomi redmi note 4 and the problem just occurs in chrome.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
      <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow></a-box>
      <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow></a-sphere>
      <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow></a-cylinder>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of Chrome? Can you describe the problem in more detail? Once the scene loads, can you rotate the camera?

Comment: if i try setting the camera position with document.getElementById('camera').setAttribute('rotation', '0 180 0'); you can see one frame that he does it and then suddenly turns around again

Comment: chrome version 68.0.3440.91 (dont forget on desktop everthings fine its about the mobileversion)

Comment: and there isnt much more detail i could explain when i open the example the camera starts on rotation 0 180 0 not 0 0 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah ok i figured out that this just happens on my xiaomi redmi note 4. If someone has also one maybe he could post it here so we know if this just my phone. Reviews about other phones with the problem would be welcome too.

Comment: If it’s device specific it could be the location of the sensor on that phone and how coordinates are reported. Does it happen on any orientation: portrait / landscape, in both directions: rotate to the left / right?

Comment: FWIW, there are reported issues with your phone sensors. Try to follow recalibration steps in this thread: http://en.miui.com/thread-458462-1-1.html

Comment: thx gonna try this. sounds very promising :D

Comment: ah i tried it nothing happend. First i thaught this must be the solution but on firefox everthing works fine so the gyro couldn´t be the problem. Looks like this phone version in combination with chrome confuses the gyro or something

Comment: ps.: camera is on normal 0 0 0 position and rotation and it occurs when you open the page on potrait and landscape

Comment: one workaround would be turning the whole scene 180 degrees but then i need a special detection for my phone or everbody else has then the turned scene

Comment: its not the most important problem to fix cause everything ist still full functioning just the "startscreen" isnt the one i had provided