# Aframe Gyroscope detection

Tags: detection, aframe, virtual-reality, gyroscope

Hiho Community,

i have this problem that sometimes the gyroscope-orientation does not work but if this occurs and i simply reload the site everything is fine.
So is there a way to detect if the gyro works, so that i can show a splashscreen ("refresh site") if the gyro does not work.

here my scene: 
https://needsomehelp.glitch.me/

https://glitch.com/~needsomehelp

The problem occurs on android firefox.
My Phone --> xiaomi redmi note 4

Comment: Only on Firefox for Android? Is Chrome working as expected?

Comment: on chrome everthing works fine expect of this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52255660/aframe-android-chrome-camera-looks-always-backward